# Insert character before specific character c#

Tags: c#, regex, string

Assuming the string below is in C#, how would one replace

```
y=x^7+3x^4-x+5
```

with

```
y=0^7+3*0^4-0+5
```

as one cannot just replace all instances of `x` with `0` as then you get `30^4`

Comment: this is mathematical expression. the easiest way is to compile string at runtime using CodeDom. even this will not work because there is no sign between 0 and x so it wont be easy algorithm to do such thing.

Comment: thanks for your answer, the problem is that i do not have a sign, so i was thinking of replacing the '3x' with 3*x, hence then i can replace x with 0 and it would work.

Comment: No this will not work for all possible expressions. sometime ago i created project understanding and calculating mathematical expression. The General algorithm was about 1500 lines of code to handle all possible expression. But codeDom is much easier and reduced my whole project in to 500 lines of code. but still too much!

Comment: You could first replace "x" with "*x", and then replace "x" with "0", and then insert "1" in the start? You should then end up with `y = 1*0^7+3*0^4+5`

Comment: Is the multiply operator the only implicit one ? Besides ["+", "-" , "*" ,"/" , "^"], is there other operators ? do you accept parenthesis ? Is x the only variable on the left? What about constants (e.g. "a", "b") ? Are functions foreseen , e.g. "log" ?

Comment: Malte R's answer did work well, and yes graffito multiply is the only implicit operator, my mathematical function handles parenthesis seperately along with other variables, and solves for x to only be on one side before proceeding with this replacing, this is a simple example :) thanks all

Comment: I doubt that Malte R answer will work on all cases (I didn't really understood its assumptions). I would have normalized the initial expression by replacing implicit operator by "*" : looping on all characters of the expression "x" must be replaced by "*x" when it is preceeded by a digit _(function char.IsDigit() can be used)_.

Comment: Yes the answer of replace x with *x fails with other operators, and I am simply trying to error catch if the user does input with implied operators, I personally use the * for multiply but others may not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var a = "y=x^7+3x^4-x+5";
var b = Regex.Replace(a, @"(\d+|[a-zA-Z])(?=\d+|[a-zA-Z])", @"$1*");
var c = Regex.Replace(b, @"x", @"0");
```

**summery of 2nd line**: match any number or variable followed by any number or variable.

**Output examples:**

```
In: y=33xggyz/3/4*x/x+xx1         |  In: y=x^7+3x^4-x+5        
Out:y=33*x*g*g*y*z/3/4*x/x+x*x*1  |  Out:y=0^7+3*0^4-0+5              
                                  |
In: y=2+33xggyz/3/4*x/x+xx        |  In: y=x1
Out:y=2+33*0*g*g*y*z/3/4*0/0+0*0  |  Out:y=0*1
                                  |
In: y=10xy^2+xx+(12x+1yy)         |  In: y(xx)=1
Out:y=10*0*y^2+0*0+(12*0+1*y*y)   |  Out:y(0*0)=1
```

**Updated:** (7/4/2015) fixed bug, failed with y=x1 (did return y=01)

Comment: Update: after additional testing I realized that the function failed with y=x0. This has been corrected.

Answer (score 0):

In this user case where you just want o change

```
y=x^7+3x^4-x+5
```

to

```
y=0^7+3*0^4-0+5
```

Would to simply add another variable.

```
int x = //Whatever x is going to be;
int j = 0;
int y = j^7+3x^4-j+5
```

Now if you have more user cases than just this one you could be adding a ton of variables very fast and in such a case you would not want to use this option. But if you are using it for an isolated case this could be a viable answer.